# SQL delete if not referenced to any item

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreign-keys

I am working on a library management website. I have a LibraryItem and Category table in my database.

What I want to do is, I want not the user to be able to delete any Categories if they are referenced in any library item.

So lets say that a category called "DVD" is referenced with a library item, and lets suppose that the user wants to delete the "DVD" category. In this case I want to tell user:

**"The category cannot be deleted because it is referenced in an item, please delete the item first if you want to delete the DVD category"**

***The Category Controller looks like this:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LibraryProject;

namespace LibraryProject.Controllers
{
    public class CategoriesController : Controller
    {
        private LibraryDbEntities db = new LibraryDbEntities();

        // GET: Categories
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Category.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Categories/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Categories/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Categories/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,CategoryName")] Category category)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Check if the cat name exists or not
                var cat = db.Category.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == category.CategoryName);
                if (cat == null)
                {
                    db.Category.Add(category);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add here the logic required to inform your user about the problem
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "This Category name already exists, choose another one!";

                }
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Categories/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Categories/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,CategoryName")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Categories/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Categories/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);
            db.Category.Remove(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I must write a line of code in the "Delete" but I just dont know how... All help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (db.Items.Any(item => item.CategoryId == id)) { /* Message */ }` ?

Comment: Get the DB to control it; `items.categoryid` is a foreign key of `categories.id`, and the relationship is specified with no cascading delete, so attempting to delete the category throws an error if items relations exist. Catch the error c# side

Comment: @itsme86 It did not work, where should I put that code? In delete?

Comment: You can't copy/paste that code because you haven't shared enough details about the models to know if there's an `Items` table or if that table has a `CategoryId` column.

Comment: @itsme86 It worked now! Thanks a lot mate!